# handsontable filtering date with datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, handsontable

Is it possible on the filter by condition to use datepicker or any calendar for the search? IE is between or is equal to fields.

my code:

```
var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: data,
    minRows: 60,
    minCols: 6,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: ["undo", "redo"],
    filters: true,
    dropdownMenu: ['filter_by_condition', 'filter_action_bar'],
    autoWrapRow: true,
    colHeaders: [
        "Date",
        "Total"
    ],
    columns: [
        {
            data: "date",
            type: "date",
            width: 120,
            dateFormat: "MM/DD/YYYY",
            readOnly: true
        },
        {
            data: "total",
            type: "numeric",
            width: 120,
            format: "0,0"
        },

    ]
});
```